# Text Field setBounds function is not working on a particular JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a JPanel with 3 text fields. Everything else including buttons is falling into place except for `textArea3`. The final panel is something like this. As you can see in picture, `textArea3` uses entire JFrame instead of following setBounds method.

```
    //Text Area 1
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 20));

    JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane jScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
    jScrollPane2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    jScrollPane2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    textArea2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea2.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea2.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 20));

    //Text Area 3
    JTextField textArea3 = new JTextField();
    textArea3.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 20));

    jScrollPane1.setBounds(30,30,300,300);
    jScrollPane2.setBounds(30,400,200,200);
    //textArea3 is not working
    textArea3.setBounds(600,800,100,50);
    button2.setBounds(350,30,80,30);

    button1.setBounds(350,400,80,30);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(jScrollPane2);
    frame.add(jScrollPane1);
    frame.add(textArea3);

    frame.setVisible(true);
```

EDIT: So this was a bug within the JDK probably. I made another class called class frame and set methods to produce text area etc.

[image: textArea3 uses entire JFrame and is not getting bound]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: Side note:  It is *not correct* to pass Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT as the second argument to a Font constructor.  As [the constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String,int,int%29) explains, the second argument is a style, which should be Font.PLAIN, Font.BOLD, Font.ITALIC, or Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC.

Comment: `textArea3.setBounds(600,800,100,50);` ← Your window is only 752 pixels high including its border.  By passing a Y coordinate of 800, you have placed your JTextArea in a location where it can’t be seen.  You really should be [using layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/) to place your components, instead of calling setBounds.

Comment: No that is not the issue. Even when I change sizes to match textArea3 uses entire window

Comment: *"No that is not the issue."* Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. BTW - I am closing this tab of the browser now, so if you want my further attention, notify me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see in picture, textArea3 uses entire JFrame instead of following setBounds method.

No I can't see. I see 5 components. I don't see any component that uses the entire frame.

If in fact you do see the text area take up the whole frame that is because:

1. the default layout manager for a JFrame is the `BorderLayout`
2. when you add components to a BorderLayout and don't specify a constraint, the CENTER is assumed.
3. however only a single component can be displayed in the CENTER so the layout manager will only give a size/location to the last component added, which happens to be textArea3.

The other components only happen to appear because you manually set the bounds of each component.

You should NOT be attempting to set the bounds of a component. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of each component.

So the solution is to get rid of all the setBounds() statement and use layout managers.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. It appears you are tying to use a grid so you can probably use a `GridBagLayout`.

Also when you create a JTextArea you should use something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 20);
```

This will allow the text area to calculate its size so that 15 rows will display with about 20 characters in each row. The size will be calculated based on the Font used.

Comment: Actually, the same methods have worked! I have created a class and created methods like ````createTextArea(int x, int y, blaa blaa)```` and they have worked perfectly fine. Really strange that this code doesn't work... Maybe some problem with my IDE... But tried Eclipse as well... Could be an OS problem...

Comment: The setBounds(). method will work (when used properly), since it is part of the JDK. However, because it does work does not mean you should be using it. It is rare to have a valid situation to use it and this is NOT one of them. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You are not doing anything special so you should follow those guidelines to prevent problems in the future. *Really strange that this code doesn't work.* - and I already explained the probable reason it is not working. It has nothing to do with your IDE.

Comment: @AdeelMalik Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.